# ./trgraph: error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ns2

Good morning community,
i wanted to install tracegraph on Ubuntu 16.04 - 32 bit:

1. i downloaded "tracegraph202" and i extracted it.
2. i downloaded "mglinstaller" and i extracted it into "tracegraph202".
3. into /home/pc/Desktop/tracegraph202/ -> ./mglinstaller
4. i copied all the files of tracegraph202, and i pasted them into **/Desktop/tracegraph202/bin/glnx86
5. export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/pc/Desktop/tracegraph202/bin/glnx86

and when i write "./trgraph", the following error apears:

> **./trgraph: error while loading shared libraries: libXp.so.6: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory**

and i cant any helpful solution on ligne ! is there any one can help me please?
Thank u so much in advance.

Comment: It is unclear what is "tracegraph202" and from where have you downloaded it?

Comment: The ancient `tracegraph202` https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/tracegraph-4175602766/#3 → #29 https://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/ns2-4175449125/page2.html : Year 2013.  **Note**: Do not expect it to work with any newish OS. ... `libXp.so.6` : Not available for Ubuntu 16.04 . Ubuntu 14.04 package, libxp6 https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/libxp6 →  https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/i386/libxp6/download

Comment: Thank you sir for answering me, but what can i do right now !?

Comment: Two modern tools are available : ns2 Trace-analyzer for Windows© http://trace-analyzer.sourceforge.net/ ... **and** ns2 APP-Tool, for e.g. Ubuntu  http://mohittahiliani.blogspot.dk/2014/10/automated-post-processing-app-tool-for.html → →  https://github.com/WiNG-NITK/APP-Tool